# android: how to operate sqlite database without running emulator?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Because I need to pre-populate the sqlite database, how can I operate on the database? Like create a table and insert some rows?

Comment: whats your question..can you explain in details ?

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/ - you can download binaries for all major platform and create/populate databases from your PC or Mac.

Comment: you just download sqllite browser into your PC and do think what you want???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the SQLite3 tool available with the Android SDK. It is in the tools folder under SDK root.

1. Add the following directory to the PATH: *{SDK root}\tools*
2. Open a command window
3. Type sqlite3

Answer (score 0):

many tools allow manipulating sqlite files. How about using the sqlite odbc driver and use a tool like microsoft access (if you have it)

http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/

Answer (score 0):

From your question I think you are unfamiliar with the Database Handling In Android.
You can very easily use a **DatabaseHandler** class and **DatabaseHelper** (extending **SQLiteOpenHelper**)

The code below explains it very well of how to use this class to do all the database operations

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHandler{
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Fruitsdb";
    private static final String TABLE_FRUITS = "fruits_table";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String CREATE_FRUITS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_FRUITS + " ("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement, " + KEY_NAME + " TEXT not null);";

    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private final Context ct;
    private DatabaseHelper dbhelper;

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context){
        this.ct=context;
        dbhelper=new DatabaseHelper(ct,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION); 
    }
    public DatabaseHandler open(){
        db=dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }
    public void close(){
        db.close();
    }
    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
        public DatabaseHelper (Context ct,String fruitname,CursorFactory cf,int ver){
            super(ct,fruitname,cf,ver);
        }
        //this oncreate method is called only once when the database is created
        //and this inserts the values into the tables the first time the app is started
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqldb) {
            sqldb.execSQL(CREATE_FRUITS_TABLE);
            List <String> lstfruits=new ArrayList<String>();
            lstfruits.add("Orange");
            lstfruits.add("Apple");
            lstfruits.add("Guava");
            lstfruits.add("Grapes");
                for(String strFruits:lstfruits){
                ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
                cv.put(KEY_NAME, strFruits);
                sqldb.insert(TABLE_FRUITS, null, cv);
            }
        }
            @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqldb, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            sqldb.execSQL("DROP TABLE OF EXISTS"+TABLE_FRUITS);
            onCreate(sqldb);
        }
    }
    public long insertEntry(String strFruit){
        //write code here of insert and change the return statement
            //using sqldb.insert(parameters..);
        return -1;
    }
    public boolean removeEntry(String strFruit){
        //write code here of delete a entery and change the return statement
            //using sqldb.delete(parameters..);
        return true;
    }
 }
```

You can call this class from your main Activity By

```
DatabaseHandler dbhandler=new DatabaseHandler(this);
dbhandler.open(); //The database is created and the values are inserted
//here you can do insert, updated ,remove,select operations
dbhandler.close();  // don't forget his one
```

This is the most simplest way of accessing and storing values in sqlite3 database. Hope it might solve your problem.